# Oracle SQL Developer can't see table after export

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer I exported a table shown below and after I exported the table I can't see the table anymore in SQL Developer. Is there any way to restore or revert back because now I cannot see the table I exported on SQL Developer anymore.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What does "can not see" mean? Can you `select * from that_table`? Can you find it in `user_objects`? Did you refresh object navigator? Which SQL Developer version do you use?

Comment: `c:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` looks like an installation folder for SQL Developer, so you probably shouldn't be saving exports there. I would make my own separate folder and use that instead.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot yea I can't find the table anymore from "select * from that_table".  I exported the table using the instructions above and afterwards the table disappeared. I restarted SQL Developer and it's still not there. My version is 20.2.0.175. Thank you.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson sounds good William I'll do that going forward. Yea the table can't be found anymore. Is there a way to reset or revert back to a previous state or connection? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the same database and user? I'm not too familiar with SQL Developer but I'd be surprised if exporting a table dropped it.

Comment: Are logged in in another schema? Can you select from the table if you prepend it with the schema name? E.g. `select * from schema_name.that_table`?

Comment: You are right, I restarted the Virtual desktop connection and it solved it. Thank you very much for your great help.